# Getting a value without duplication

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to get a value from a table that joins on multiple rows?

For example:

table 1 has a unique row with a unique transaction

table 2 has many rows that join on A because it's a balance sheet

I only need a single value (account) from a particular subset of columns in table 2 whose rows are duplicates in every way apart from the date.

When I join table 2 onto table 1 I get a lot of duplication because of the different dates.

```
SELECT table1.transaction,table2.account
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.table1_key
WHERE table2.account = '343'
```

The row from table1 might look like this:

```
key: 1, transaction: 200
```

The entries from table2 would look like this:

```
key: 1, transaction: 200, date:31/01, account: 343, table1_key: 1
key: 2, transaction: 200, date:28/02, account: 343, table1_key: 1
key: 3, transaction: 200, date:31/03, account: 343, table1_key: 1
key: 4, transaction: 200, date:30/04, account: 343, table1_key: 1
```

I'm brand new to SQL so not sure if this is enough info. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SQL. Post your table descriptions? And any SQL you may have already tried. Will help those around you to better understand your problem. With this example you are always going to get multiple rows, so this will help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DISTINCT` clause in your query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.transaction,table2.account
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.table1_key
WHERE table2.account = '343'
```